# Voice type question

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I have a question that's been on my mind a lot.My voice is naturally low.But my vocal range extended from D3-G5 (two years ago) but now it is C3-C6 with a whistle note A#6...What does that make me? I am a girl.

Comment: Man, I wish I could whistle that high. Other than that, the second one actually sounds similar to my range.

Answer (score 0):

Many people would consider you a mezzo soprano (most mezzo soprano ranges lie between A below middle C and up to C6 for those with fairly high range).

Comment: The C6 might be possible with a special mezzo, but I doubt it would be produced incredibly comfortably, accurately, consistently, or wouldn't drain the singer too much. If you're writing high C's for your average mezzo, they're not being used correctly. A5 is pretty safe for a top-of-range note.